# override login fosuserbundle to include register option

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I've successfully changed the template for the login but I want to include to option for a new user to register if they don't have a login information.

I tried simply including this: `{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}`
 but nothing changed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I was having trouble finding the path for registering a user...

`<a href = "{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}">Register Here</a>`

...Thats all

Comment: You can always use `php app/console debug:router | grep register` (On linux) to see all routes that have `register` in them, or `php app/console debug:router > file.txt` (On Windows, and open the newly created `file.txt` in the project directory) - with the same effect. If you are using symfony3, you'll have to use `bin` insetead of `app`. Or, if you want to see all your routes, simply write `php app/console debug:router` (or `php app/console debug:router > file.txt`).